# Вводное слово и нет ? (что ли)

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

**- Ну а что, разве мы не белорусы(,) что ли?
- Ты дурак(,) что ли?**

Скажите, пожалуйста, какую функцию выполняет сочетание "что ли" и нужны ли запятые. Спасибо.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Частицы ***что ли***, ***или*** вносят значение неуверенного предположения или подчеркивают это значение, если оно выражено другими средствами: ***Больной он, что ли?***; ***Пальто у тебя новое, что ли?***; Терпи, пока не улечу. Или полетишь со мной? (Симон.). Частица или служит также для установления альтернативных отношений между предполагаемым (в вопросе) и тем, о чем говорится перед этим: Где же наш пахарь? Чего еще ждет? Или мы хуже других уродились? Или не дружно цвели - колосились? (Некр.); У-у, меня что-то в жар кинуло. Или здесь вообще жарко? (Шукш.). ***Частица что ли обычно заключает собою предложение, но с целью подчеркивания того, о чем спрашивается, эта частица может помещаться в середине предложения вслед за соответствующим словом: Сюда, что ли, квартирантку-то вашу определить? (Бунин).*** Употребление частицы что ли в начале предложения возможно в просторечии: Что ли к дежурному вас отвести?; Что ли нам чайку попить? (разг. речь). Частица или помещается в начале предложения.(http://rusgram.narod.ru/2591-2640.html)

Если частица ***что ли*** стоит в середине предложения или завершает предложение, как в Ваших примерах, то она выделяется запятой (запятыми).